# App links not working on firefox, but chrome works

Tags: android, applinks

I have a demo to verify android app links, it's work fine on chrome browser, but doesn't work on Firefox.

My website: https://gracious-ride-bc7d4b.netlify.com after click the link

[Open native App](https://brave-neumann-713e24.netlify.com/applinks)

Chrome will open my native app directly, but Firefox just open url in browser.

Is that something error with my code or not? Please advise.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue???

Comment: I'm interested in it, too

Comment: @Madhu And you found a solution?